# Jacobian method for $Z=X/Y$

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

I'm having trouble to solve this problem with the Jacobian method.

Let $\mathbb{I}_{[0,1]^2}(x,y)$ the density of a random vector $(X,Y)$ with $X\perp Y$, i have to find the density of $Z=\frac{X}{Y}$ without the formule $f_{Z}(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|x|f_{X}(x)f_Y(zx)dx$.

After using the transformation $g=\left\{\begin{matrix}
u=\frac{x}{y}\\ 
v=y\end{matrix}\right.$ $\Rightarrow $
$g'=\left\{\begin{matrix}
x=uv\\ 
y=v\end{matrix}\right.$ and calculating the Jacobian matrix (that is $v$ with $dxdy=vdudv$) I have:

$\mathbb{E}[g(\frac{X}{Y})]=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}g(\frac{x}{y})f(x,y)dxdy=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}g(\frac{x}{y})\mathbb{I}_{[0,1]^{2}}(x,y)dxdy=\int_{0}^{1}v[\int_{0}^{1}g(u)du]dv$

But now i don't understand what are the extremes of integration.

Could you help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: We have $0<x<1$ and $0<y<1$ so $0<uv<1$ and $0<v<1$ which implies $0<u<1/v$ and $0<v<1/u$.

Comment: @Math1000 Thanks for your answer. Are you sure? So (trivially) the result is $\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{u}}g(u)v[\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{v}}du]dv=\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{u}}g(u)dv=\frac{1}{u}\Rightarrow Z=\frac{X}{Y}\sim \frac{1}{u}\mathbb{I}_{[0,\frac{1}{v}]}(u)$ ? Is it possible?

Comment: I am not entirely sure, have not had enough coffee yet. That is just what seemed to me at first glance looking at the inequalities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process is purely mechanical.

Pdf of $(X,Y)$ is $$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\mathbf1_{0<x,y<1}$$

Changing variables $(x,y)\to (u,v)$, you have $$0<x,y<1\implies 0<uv<1\,,\,0<v<1$$

So pdf of $(U,V)$ is just $$f_{U,V}(u,v)=f_{X,Y}(uv,v)|v|=v\mathbf1_{0<uv<1,0<v<1}$$

Hence pdf of $U$ is $$f_U(u)=\int f_{U,V}(u,v)\,dv=\int_0^{\min(1,1/u)}v\,dv=\cdots$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So $\frac{X}{Y}\sim \left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{I}_{[0,1]}(u)\\ 
\frac{1}{2u^2}\mathbb{I}_{[(-\infty,0)\cup (1,+\infty)]}(u)
\end{matrix}\right.$ ? Is it correct?

Comment: Rather $$f_U(u)=\frac12\mathbf1_{0<u<1}+\frac1{2u^2}\mathbf1_{u>1}$$

Comment: Right, negative part is not included. Thanks again!